# How to get background to show full image

Tags: html, css, image, background

I am trying to get the background image to show the full picture no matter the size of the browser. When I make the browser full screen it cuts off the background image.

I have fiddled with height and background-size.

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/838ffe3b51b82759591aafe1ad820f47/tumblr_pexmxzbbjQ1ukgu7do1_1280.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: ;
}
```

expected result background to always show full pic no matter the browser size. Actual result background cuts off pic short when full screen. I need to see the full light bulb.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could set the width and height to 100%:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
};

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/838ffe3b51b82759591aafe1ad820f47/tumblr_pexmxzbbjQ1ukgu7do1_1280.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
};
```